# What is the logic behind forming co-ordinate points for circle in opengl

Tags: opengl, geometry

I need explanation for following code.

```
float stepSize = ((2*M_PI)/POINTS_1349);
for (float d = 0; d <= (2*M_PI)-stepSize; d += stepSize) {
        pPointer->x = sin(d) * 0.5;  //0.5 is radius
        pPointer->y = cos(d) * 0.5;
        pPointer->z = 0.0f;
        pPointer->w = 1.0f;
        pPointer++;
}
```

Where POINTS indicate number of points used to form a circle.
M_PI=3.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle is defined here in parametric way, where the points that form the curve are:

```
    x[i] = R * sin(angle[i]);
    y[i] = R * cos(angle[i]);
```

And angle is:

```
    angle[i] = 2 * PI / N * i;
```

`N` is number of points and `i` runs over values in `[0..N)` range.